# Audio recording implementation in web2py using recorder.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, web2py, bower

I am developing a web app in which i want to use recorder.js file to implement audio recording. I have this code but i am unable to use in web2py framework. Can you give me detail info how to use it?
There is a .bower.json file which is getting hidden on uploading in web2py. how can we use this and link all the files so that recording can be done?

This is my .bower.json script:

```
 {
  "name": "Recorderjs",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs",
  "_release": "f814ac7b3f",
  "_resolution": {
"type": "branch",
"branch": "master",
"commit": "f814ac7b3f4ed4f62729860d5a02720f167480b3"
  },
 "_source": "git://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs.git",
 "_target": "*",
 "_originalSource": "Recorderjs",
 "_direct": true
 }
```

This is my html code:

```
<body>
<script src="bower_components/Recorderjs/recorder.js">
</script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

<button onclick="record()">Record</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

These are my javascripts:  /app.js

```
var navigator = window.navigator;
var Context = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new Context();

// audio
var mediaStream;
var rec;
navigator.getUserMedia = (
navigator.getUserMedia ||
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
navigator.msGetUserMedia
);

function record() {
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, function(localMediaStream){
mediaStream = localMediaStream;
var mediaStreamSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(localMediaStream);
rec = new Recorder(mediaStreamSource, {
  workerPath: '/bower_components/Recorderjs/recorderWorker.js'
});

 rec.record();
 }, function(err){
 console.log('Not supported');
 });
 }

 function stop() {
 mediaStream.stop();
 rec.stop();

rec.exportWAV(function(e){
rec.clear();
Recorder.forceDownload(e, "test.wav");
});
}
```

/recorder.js

```
(function(window){

  var WORKER_PATH = 'recorderWorker.js';

  var Recorder = function(source, cfg){
  var config = cfg || {};
   var bufferLen = config.bufferLen || 4096;
this.context = source.context;
this.node = (this.context.createScriptProcessor ||
             this.context.createJavaScriptNode).call(this.context,
                                                     bufferLen, 2, 2);
var worker = new Worker(config.workerPath || WORKER_PATH);
worker.postMessage({
  command: 'init',
  config: {
    sampleRate: this.context.sampleRate
  }
});
var recording = false,
  currCallback;

this.node.onaudioprocess = function(e){
  if (!recording) return;
  worker.postMessage({
    command: 'record',
    buffer: [
      e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0),
      e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(1)
    ]
  });
}

this.configure = function(cfg){
  for (var prop in cfg){
    if (cfg.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      config[prop] = cfg[prop];
    }
  }
}

this.record = function(){
  recording = true;
}

this.stop = function(){
  recording = false;
}

this.clear = function(){
  worker.postMessage({ command: 'clear' });
}

this.getBuffer = function(cb) {
  currCallback = cb || config.callback;
  worker.postMessage({ command: 'getBuffer' })
}
```

recorderWorker.js:

```
var recLength = 0,
recBuffersL = [],
recBuffersR = [],
sampleRate;

this.onmessage = function(e){
switch(e.data.command){
case 'init':
  init(e.data.config);
  break;
case 'record':
  record(e.data.buffer);
  break;
case 'exportWAV':
  exportWAV(e.data.type);
  break;
case 'getBuffer':
  getBuffer();
  break;
case 'clear':
  clear();
  break;
  }
  };

 function init(config){
 sampleRate = config.sampleRate;
 }

  function record(inputBuffer){
  recBuffersL.push(inputBuffer[0]);
  recBuffersR.push(inputBuffer[1]);
  recLength += inputBuffer[0].length;
  }

 function exportWAV(type){
 var bufferL = mergeBuffers(recBuffersL, recLength);
 var bufferR = mergeBuffers(recBuffersR, recLength);
 var interleaved = interleave(bufferL, bufferR);
 var dataview = encodeWAV(interleaved);
 var audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], { type: type });

 this.postMessage(audioBlob);
 }

 function getBuffer() {
 var buffers = [];
 buffers.push( mergeBuffers(recBuffersL, recLength) );
 buffers.push( mergeBuffers(recBuffersR, recLength) );
 this.postMessage(buffers);
  }

 function clear(){
 recLength = 0;
 recBuffersL = [];
 recBuffersR = [];
 }

 function mergeBuffers(recBuffers, recLength){
 var result = new Float32Array(recLength);
 var offset = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < recBuffers.length; i++){
 result.set(recBuffers[i], offset);
 offset += recBuffers[i].length;
 }
 return result;
 }

function interleave(inputL, inputR){
 var length = inputL.length + inputR.length;
   var result = new Float32Array(length);

  var index = 0,
   inputIndex = 0;

   while (index < length){
   result[index++] = inputL[inputIndex];
   result[index++] = inputR[inputIndex];
    inputIndex++;
    }
    return result;
   }

      function floatTo16BitPCM(output, offset, input){
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++, offset+=2){
      var s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, input[i]));
     output.setInt16(offset, s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7FFF, true);
     }
     }

     function writeString(view, offset, string){
      for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
      view.setUint8(offset + i, string.charCodeAt(i));
      }
      }

      function encodeWAV(samples){
      var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + samples.length * 2);
      var view = new DataView(buffer);

      /* RIFF identifier */
        writeString(view, 0, 'RIFF');
     /* file length */
       view.setUint32(4, 32 + samples.length * 2, true);
      /* RIFF type */
       writeString(view, 8, 'WAVE');
      /* format chunk identifier */
         writeString(view, 12, 'fmt ');
       /* format chunk length */
        view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
        /* sample format (raw) */
       view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
      /* channel count */
        view.setUint16(22, 2, true);
     /* sample rate */
      view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
       /* byte rate (sample rate * block align) */
      view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 4, true);
      /* block align (channel count * bytes per sample) */
      view.setUint16(32, 4, true);
         /* bits per sample */
            view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
       /* data chunk identifier */
        writeString(view, 36, 'data');
        /* data chunk length */
         view.setUint32(40, samples.length * 2, true);

          floatTo16BitPCM(view, 44, samples);

          return view;
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the only problem, but the following script source references are relative URLs:

```
<script src="bower_components/Recorderjs/recorder.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Because the URLs are not preceded with a `/`, they will be appended to the URL of the current page. So, if you are at `/myapp/default/index`, the first URL will reference `/myapp/default/index/bower_components/Recorderjs/recorder.js`, which will not be correct.

You should keep your Javascript files in the `/web2py/applications/myapp/static` folder. In that case, it is best to use the web2py `URL()` function to generate proper URLs:

```
<script src="{{=URL('static', 'js/bower_components/Recorderjs/recorder.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{=URL('static', 'js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

Regarding internal URLs, assuming you move everything into the /myapp/static/js folder, a URL like:

```
/bower_components/Recorderjs/recorderWorker.js
```

would change to:

```
/myapp/static/js/bower_components/Recorderjs/recorderWorker.js
```

Relative internal URLs should continue to work without alteration.

Comment: Do i have to change anything in this to upload in web2py ?

    {
     "name": "Recorderjs",
     "homepage": "https://github.com/web2py/Recorderjs",
      "_release": "f814ac7b3f",
      "_resolution": {
      "type": "branch",
     "branch": "master",
     "commit": "f814ac7b3f4ed4f62729860d5a02720f167480b3"
     },
    "_source": "git://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs.git",
     "_target": "*",
    "_originalSource": "Recorderjs",
    "_direct": true
   }

Comment: I'm not sure. Try it and see what happens. In general, any JS library should work with web2py -- you just have to make sure your script `src` references the correct URL and any other internal URLs are correct.

Comment: we are unable to understand what shuld be the correct internal URL in the scripts (worker paths in app.js, recorder.js) and .bower.json file